# Value of selected item from SelectOneMenu does not get set in converter

Tags: jsf, converters, selectonemenu

In a JSF project I have a SelectOneMenu populated by a list of string values and connected to an Integer value "yearStart". 
When I select a value from the list, the converter always outputs to the console "stringVal = null".
Why doesn't the value of the selected item get to the converter?

My web page includes the following:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{applicantController.yearStart}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{yearList.years}" />
    <f:converter converterId="studyYearConverter"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

It uses this list of years:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class YearList implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final List<String> years = Arrays.asList("prior to 1990", "1990",
        "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998",
        "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006",
        "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013");

    public List<String> getYears() {
        return years;
    }

}
```

My converter class:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "studyYearConverter")
public class StudyYearConverter implements Converter {

    private static final String PRIOR_TO_1990 = "prior to 1990";

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            String stringVal) {
        if (PRIOR_TO_1990.equals(stringVal)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("stringVal = " + stringVal);  
            // Why is this alway null??
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(stringVal);
            } catch (NumberFormatException pe) {
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(
                       "Invalid date format. Valid format e.g. 2010-04");
                throw new ConverterException(message);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
        if (value == null || !(value instanceof Integer)) {
                return null;
        } else {
            Integer year = (Integer) value;
            if (year == -1) {
                return PRIOR_TO_1990;
            } else {
                return year.toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the `getAsString` method. Try to debug there and check why it's falling in the `!(value instanceof Integer)` condition (hint: you have a `List<String>` for your years, not a `List<Integer>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supplying the items the converter expects.

The `getAsString()` method is used during rendering the HTML response. At this point, (possibly) complex Java objects needs to be converted to its unique `String` representation so that they can be represented in HTML. The `getAsObject()` method is used during applying the HTTP request parameter values. HTTP request parameter values can like HTML input values only be represented as `String` and in order to get the complex Java object back, the unique `String` representation has to be converted.

You've a `List<String>` as available item values. So when every single item is about to be rendered to HTML, it goes through `getAsString()`. However, you're performing an `instanceof Integer` check, which would always fail and thus return `null` for every single item. So you end up with a valueless `<option>` in the generated HTML which get submitted as `null`. That's why your `getAsObject()` end up getting `null`s.

Based on the attempt so far, I have the impression that `#{applicantController.yearStart}` is actually an `Integer` which you'd like to set with the year, or `-1` if "Prior to 1990" is selected. If you'd like to keep your converter, then you should be changing the available items to

```
private final List<Integer> years = Arrays.asList(-1, 1990,
        1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998,
        1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
        2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013);
```

Comment: Very nicely explained. That helped me understand what's actually going on. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I know which could be the solution.
You should store the list and selected element in properties and maintain them in the scope as long as the component is used.

Comment: OP is already using `@ApplicationScoped` for that. This is thus very definitely not the cause of OP's particular problem.

Comment: believe or not I removed in a similar situation the equals and hashcode and it worked. Then I decided to use a DTO instead of the real object to maintain in my entity hashcode and equals. But my dto only has the needed attributes + serializable implementation. And finally worked.

Comment: Your approach is totally flawed, trust me.